# inserting OSM overpass API using Node.js to Postgresql

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, overpass-api

The other elements such as id, tags, and type of the object can sucessfully inserted to the database. However, the columns of lat and lon is giving null value. I tried the column type of (decimal, varchar, double, and float). and here is the javascript code of index.js

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QAY4Ga-9Vcjn41ChInM4vhsS-e6jF2Op?usp=drive_link
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJXDY.png)
null value in database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zU1B.png) log in console showing latitude and longitude

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.